# webrtc onicecandidate event trigger

Tags: javascript, networking, connection, webrtc, peer

I wonder why webrtc has this behaviour:
after I create a peer connection, i declare the onicecandidate event handler, which will conosle log the connecion's local description. Then I create an offer and set the sdp that is returned as the connection's local description. the event handler is triggered however the local description is never conosle loged. However whenever I create a data channel before creating the offer, the local description is returned on the console. Can someone explain to me why this happens?

example without data channel

```
const lc = new RTCPeerConnection();

lc.onicecandidate = e => console.log(JSON.stringify(lc.localDescription));

lc.createOffer().then(o=>lc.setLocalDescription(o)).then(console.log('offer set'))
```

the console returns :
Promise {}

example with data channel

```
const lc = new RTCPeerConnection();

lc.onicecandidate = e => console.log(JSON.stringify(lc.localDescription));

lc.createDataChannel("xan")

lc.createOffer().then(o=>lc.setLocalDescription(o)).then(console.log('offer set'))
```

the console returns : Promise {} , the localDescription

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer could be the fact that there are no MediaStreamTracks attached to the connection in the first case